# PHP Curl to retrive soccer results for personal site shows blank page

Tags: php, curl

Simple PHP code to retrieve information from a site gives me blank page.

```
$url='http://www.livescore.com/';
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
echo file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Your code is working. Make sure curl is installed on your machine.

Comment: Your code is correct. Probably something with curl in your PHP, or something else. Try debug into php error logs..

Comment: Thanks Serhat and Vladimir.
This code is working for certain "simple" sites, but not for this one and others.
I'm actually trying to code in php and upload my php files in a server space and run from there.

Comment: Your code works for livescore.com from my machine...